# The SQL statement is only allowed as the first statement in a unit of work. SQLSTATE=25001

Tags: db2

I am trying to call a stored procedure from a new schema.I mean i have created few procedures on one db2 server & taken the backup file of that & installed on other db2 server. 
When I am trying to call the procedure : it is giving the below error:

call prroc1();
SQL0428N  The SQL statement is only allowed as the first statement in a unit
of work.  SQLSTATE=25001

can some one explain me , what i am getting here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1 (IN pl VARCHAR(10),IN it VARCHAR(10), 
IN  pi VARCHAR(20),IN yu INTEGER)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

 COMMIT;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM JREO.8769';
 COMMIT;

 CALL Q298080();

 CALL WIUTYI.295(WIUYT,WYTIO,IUEYT,ERT); 

END P1
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you'll need to provide the code for `prroc1()` for people to be able to help you.

Comment: There is a call to nested procedures over this single prroc1()

Comment: You will get this error if you have truncate statement in the procedure anywhere other than first statement.